# Backbone Model Access Static Method in Model itself

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How do I access a static method of a model inside the model's function itself?

For instance, say I have the following:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    tableName : 'models',
    someFunction: function() {
        // Want to access 'someArray' here
    }
}, {
    someArray: ['a', 'b', 'c']
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    tableName : 'models',
    someFunction: function() {
        console.log(Model.someArray);
    }
}, {
    someArray: ['a', 'b', 'c']
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?